# Permission denied when accessing VirtualBox shared folder when member of the vboxsf group

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shared-folders

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 (guest) on Windows 7 (host) with the guest additions installed. I have an auto-mount folder that maps to my D: drive on the host which I can access using `sudo ls /media/sf_D_DRIVE` - however, even when my user (ross) is a member of the vboxsf group I get a permission denied error when attempting to explore it. I have restarted since adding my user to the vboxsf group.

This should work because I am a member of the group (which has rwx rights), so why doesn't it?

```
ross@panther:~$ ls -l /media
total 8
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 8192 2011-07-03 22:24 sf_D_DRIVE

ross@panther:~$ ls -l /media/sf_D_DRIVE/
ls: cannot open directory /media/sf_D_DRIVE/: Permission denied

ross@panther:~$ id ross
uid=1000(ross) gid=1000(ross) groups=1000(ross),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),46(plugdev),112(lpadmin),120(admin),122(sambashare),1001(vboxsf)

ross@panther:~$ sudo ls -l /media/sf_D_DRIVE/
total 84
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 2011-07-06 14:46 Development
# ...snip...
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 2011-05-25 19:13 Videos
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I had added my user to the vboxsf group:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $(whoami)
```

I did do a restart, but after logging out and in again, I got access! Restarting after this and it still works. Go figure.

Comment: why is the need for a restart?

Comment: Not sure, it just seemed to correct itself.

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69221/adding-user-to-a-group-why-had-to-reboot) why a restart is required. A logout/login would do.

Comment: This answer command has to be run on the **GUEST** machine!

Comment: Just tried this with Lubuntu 16.04, my user was created in the `vboxsf` group, however it was not checked... so was *added* but *disabled*. Checking the username and logging out/in or rebooting got it working.

Comment: I tried a simple logout login but it didn't work. I had to restart.

Comment: I still don't understand why a reboot would be necessary; i.e. why a logout/login would not be sufficient. If a Linux server had to reboot every time they added a user to a group, it would be an absolute mess.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently logging out is insufficient, which seems strange if it was just a matter of being a member of a group. However, this seems to do the trick, without a system reboot:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $(whoami)
sudo systemctl restart vboxadd-service.service
```

which suggests that it is not simply a matter of being a member of the appropriate group.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this procedure:
Check that your user account is in the vboxsf group. Click on the bird icon, select Users and Groups → Manage Groups → vboxsf → Properties. Your user account should have a checkmark next to it. Check it if it is unchecked. When prompted for a password, enter secret.

Then a restart on the virtual machine (Power of the Machine) and this allowed for the shared folder to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "bird icon"?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your kali linux terminal then run the command below:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf (your-kali-username)

sudo chown -R (your-kali-username):users /media/(your-share-folder-name)
```

Below is a sample use:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf tahmid

sudo chown -R tahmid:users /media/sf_pen_drive
```

Comment: The sudo chown -R was necessary for me too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Comment: The OP has already said they have guest additions installed.

Comment: I hadn't and this made it work