# VirtualBox shared folder got permission denied on a vboxsf group

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux, shared-folders

I got similar problem with this one [Permission denied when accessing VirtualBox shared folder when member of the vboxsf group](https://superuser.com/questions/307853/permission-denied-when-accessing-virtualbox-shared-folder-when-member-of-the-vbo). Instead, I'm running ArchLinux. As it is also has mentioned in the [official wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Enable_shared_folders), I've put my user to the vboxsf group and I can see it through `id`. The thing is that I got permission denied when accessing the folder. Here is the case:

```
# spondbob at bikinibottom-vb in ~ [12:42:18]
$ ls /media/sf_share_folder
ls: cannot access /media/sf_share_folder: Permission denied

# spondbob at bikinibottom-vb in ~ [12:41:43]
$ sudo ls -l /media/
total 0
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Dec 12 23:17 sf_share_folder

# spondbob at bikinibottom-vb in ~ [12:41:52]
$ sudo ls -l /media/sf_share_folder
total 5
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 Dec 12 23:51 projects
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    4 Dec 12 23:13 tes.txt

# spondbob at bikinibottom-vb in ~ [12:41:54]
$ id
uid=1000(spondbob) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),10(wheel),95(storage),98(power),109(vboxsf)

# spondbob at bikinibottom-vb in ~ [12:41:59]
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 spondbob users 22 Dec 13 12:04 share_folder -> /media/sf_share_folder

# spondbob at bikinibottom-vb in ~ [12:42:07]
$ ls share_folder
ls: cannot access share_folder: Permission denied
```

Any help to resolve the permission is appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem using another method, which is mounting on boot using fstab. More information about that is on this page https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191120